# Is there any possible way to append an event (custom made) to an object created in run-time ?[C++ Builder]

Tags: c++, c++builder

So, i have tried to create some TEdit objects in run-time, eventually what I'm trying to find out is: **How am i supposed to create a custom OnClick event and append it to an Object in run-time**, for example, the event should take 2 parameters, the Sender object(obviously) and the index of the TEdit object. The event should change some properties of the TEdit object created in run-time, whose index would be passed as a parameter, so the Text property would be like : "Enter some values in the [index] edit", or something in this manner.

```
Edit=new TEdit*[nr_elem];

    for(int i=0;i<nr_elem;i++)
    {
    Edit[i]=new TEdit(this);

    Edit[i]->Width=75;
    Edit[i]->Height=20;
    Edit[i]->Top=100+15*i;
    Edit[i]->Left=50;
    Edit[i]->Parent=Form1;
   /** Now I should append the event to the Edit[i] object*/
}
```

The event should look like:

```
 void __fastcall TForm1::EditNClick(TObject *Sender,int index)
{
    Edit[index]->Text="Enter some value in the"+AnsiString(index)+" box";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a handler that does not match the signature that `OnClick` is expecting:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TNotifyEvent)(System::TObject* Sender);
```

Which means you cannot add extra parameters at all.

However, you can assign a single `OnClick` handler to all of the `TEdit` controls, and then leverage the `Sender` parameter to know which `TEdit` is being clicked on, eg:

```cpp
Edit = new TEdit*[nr_elem];

for(int i = 0; i < nr_elem; ++i)
{
    Edit[i] = new TEdit(this);

    Edit[i]->Width = 75;
    Edit[i]->Height = 20;
    Edit[i]->Top = 100+15*i;
    Edit[i]->Left = 50;
    Edit[i]->Parent = this;
    Edit[i]->Tag = i;
    Edit[i]->OnClick = EditClick;
}

...

void __fastcall TForm1::EditClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *Edit = static_cast<TEdit*>(Sender);
    EditNClick(Edit, Edit->Tag);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::EditNClick(TEdit *Sender, int index)
{
    Sender->Text = _D("Enter some value in the ") + String(index) + _D(" box");
}
```

If you don't want to rely on the `Tag` (ie, if you are using it for something else), or if you want to attach additional custom data to each Edit, you can use a custom derived class instead:

```cpp
class TMyEdit : public TEdit
{
public:
    int ArrayIndex;
    ...
    __fastcall TMyEdit(TComponent *Owner) : TEdit(Owner) {}
};

...

Edit = new TEdit*[nr_elem];

for(int i = 0; i < nr_elem; ++i)
{
    Edit[i] = new TMyEdit(this);

    Edit[i]->Width = 75;
    Edit[i]->Height = 20;
    Edit[i]->Top = 100+15*i;
    Edit[i]->Left = 50;
    Edit[i]->Parent = this;
    static_cast<TMyEdit*>(Edit[i])->ArrayIndex = i;
    Edit[i]->OnClick = EditClick;
}

...

void __fastcall TForm1::EditClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMyEdit *Edit = static_cast<TMyEdit*>(Sender);
    EditNClick(Edit, Edit->ArrayIndex);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::EditNClick(TEdit *Sender, int index)
{
    Sender->Text = _D("Enter some value in the ") + String(index) + _D(" box");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to embed the index in the TEdit Tag field, then give them all the same OnClick handler:

```
    Edit[i]->Left=50;
    Edit[i]->Parent=Form1;
    Edit[i]->Tag = i;
    Edit[i]->OnClick = myclick;
```

Then the myclick handler could be:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::myclick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (TEdit * ed = dynamic_cast<TEdit *>(Sender))
    {
        ed->Text="Enter some value in the"+AnsiString(ed->Tag)+" box";
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Since you KNOW the `Sender` will always be a `TEdit`, you should use `static_cast` instead, and get rid of the `if` statement entirely.